# decimal places auto format in price jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to covert decimal places `on` type `input` field like

Number starts from `0.00`

so at first place it will be `0.00` in input field

than i type `1` than it should become `0.01`

than i type `2` than it should become `0.12`

than `0` so it should become `1.20` and lastly

when i type `0` than it should become `12.00`

`0.01`, `0.12`, `1.20`, `12.00`.

I tried some methods which already given in SO but not successful.

Please suggest me another methods if possible. thank you.

i tried like this

```js
$(document).on('keyup','.price',function(e){
  var value = $(this).val();
  if(value.length <= 6) {
   if(e.which == 190 || e.which == 46 || e.which == 44 || e.which == 188){
    var amountDots = 0;
    var amountCommas = 0;
    if(value.indexOf(',') > -1){
     amountCommas = value.match(/,/gi).length;
    }
    if(value.indexOf('.') > -1){
     amountDots = value.match(/./gi).length;
    }
    if((amountDots >= 1 && amountCommas >= 1) || amountCommas > 1 || value.length == 1){
     $(this).val(value.substr(0,value.length - 1));
     return false;
    }
    else{
      $(this).val(value.substr(0, value.length - 1) + ',');
    }
   }
      
   $(this).val(value/100); //here is the value will insert
      
  } else {
   $(this).val(value.substr(0,value.length - 1))
   return false;
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="price" />
```

Comment: I would recommend either one of these libraries: [jQuery Mask plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) or [jQuery InputMask](https://plugins.jquery.com/jquery.inputmask/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, totally different solution that works when deleting characters:

```
$(document).on('keypress','.price',function(e){
    var char = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    if(isNaN(char)) char = '';
    var value = $(this).val() + char;
    value = value.replace('.','');
    $(this).val((value/100).toFixed(2));
    if(!isNaN(char)) return false;
}).on('keyup','.price',function(e){
    var value = $(this).val();
    value = value.replace('.','');
    $(this).val((value/100).toFixed(2));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/14shzdo5/

Comment: this is working like a charm! but while you delete the characters it retains the old value in `rel` attribute as it is.

Comment: is there any solution for this? Try typing `1, 0, 0` and then delete them all, and re-type `1`, you will see it does not start from `0.01`

Comment: @NiravJoshi please check my new solution, it works in all cases

Comment: Appreciated. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

The following logic works for the basic scenario. You may have to separately handle clearing out the text input.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#my-input").on('keyup', function(e) {
    
    var v = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);

    if (!isNaN(v)) {
      var dv = $("#my-display").val();
      $("#my-display").val(dv + '' + v);
      $(this).val(($("#my-display").val() / 100).toFixed(2));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="my-input" />
<input type="hidden" id="my-display" />
```

Comment: Try typing 1, 0, 0 and then delete them all, and re-type 1, you will see it does not start from `0.01`.

Comment: I answered with _You may have to separately handle clearing out the text input_. I just addressed the logical issue.

Comment: yeah I noticed that, that's why I deleted my comment, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

With each new keystroke, assuming it's a number, append it to the end, multiply by 10 and display the result.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but I thought this might help people in the future. Covers a lot of useful cases.

Try out here: https://codepen.io/mswarts/pen/poGbmML

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="fixedDecimals" value="0" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
// Configuration variables
let decimalPlaces;
let unit;
let unitPosition; // "before" or "after"
let useDigitSeparator;
let numberSystem;

// Define the number systems
const numberSystems = {
    1: { digitSeparator: ",", decimalSeparator: ".", digitGroups: 3 },
    2: { digitSeparator: ".", decimalSeparator: ",", digitGroups: 3 },
    3: { digitSeparator: " ", decimalSeparator: ",", digitGroups: 3 },
    4: { digitSeparator: "'", decimalSeparator: ".", digitGroups: 3 },
    5: { digitSeparator: ",", decimalSeparator: ".", digitGroups: 4 },
};

function formatNumber(numStr) {
    const ns = numberSystems[numberSystem];
    let whole, decimal;

    if (decimalPlaces > 0) {
        decimal = numStr.slice(-decimalPlaces).padStart(decimalPlaces, '0');
        whole = numStr.slice(0, -decimalPlaces) || '0';
    } else {
        whole = numStr;
        decimal = '';  // Explicitly set 'decimal' to an empty string when there are no decimal places.
    }

    whole = parseInt(whole, 10).toString();

    if (useDigitSeparator) {
        const regex = new RegExp(`\\B(?=(\\d{${ns.digitGroups}})+(?!\\d))`, 'g');
        whole = whole.replace(regex, ns.digitSeparator);
    }

    const spacer = unit.trim() ? ' ' : '';
    const formattedNum = decimalPlaces > 0 ? `${whole}${ns.decimalSeparator}${decimal}` : whole;
    return unitPosition === "before" ? `${unit}${spacer}${formattedNum}` : `${formattedNum}${spacer}${unit}`;
}

function enforceCursorPosition(el) {
    let cursorPosition = el.value.length;
    if (unitPosition === "after") {
        cursorPosition -= (unit.length + 1);
    }
    el.setSelectionRange(cursorPosition, cursorPosition);
}

function handlePaste(e) {
    const pastedData = e.clipboardData.getData('text');
    let pastedRawValue = pastedData.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

    // Current content of the input without non-numeric characters
    let currentRawValue = inputElement.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

    // Remove leading zeroes from the current content
    currentRawValue = currentRawValue.replace(/^0+/, '');

    // Concatenate the current content with the pasted content
    let combinedValue = currentRawValue + pastedRawValue;

    // If the combined value exceeds 15 characters, remove characters from the end
    while (combinedValue.length > 15) {
        combinedValue = combinedValue.substring(0, combinedValue.length - 1);
    }

    const formattedValue = formatNumber(combinedValue);
    inputElement.value = formattedValue;
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default paste operation.
    enforceCursorPosition(inputElement);
}

function inputHandler(e) {
    let targetValue = e ? e.target.value : inputElement.value;
    let rawValue = targetValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    
    // Ensure rawValue doesn't exceed 15 characters
    if (rawValue.length > 15) {
        rawValue = rawValue.substring(0, 15);
    }

    const formattedValue = formatNumber(rawValue);

    if (e) {
        e.target.value = formattedValue;
        enforceCursorPosition(e.target);
    } else {
        inputElement.value = formattedValue;
    }
}

const inputElement = document.querySelector('.fixedDecimals');

inputElement.addEventListener('input', inputHandler);

inputElement.addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);

inputElement.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    // Allow Command or Ctrl key combinations
    if (e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey) {
        return;
    }

    // Allow shift + arrow keys for text selection
    if (e.shiftKey && (e.key === 'ArrowLeft' || e.key === 'ArrowRight')) {
        return;
    }

    if (!(e.key.match(/[0-9]/) || e.key === 'Backspace')) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    setTimeout(() => enforceCursorPosition(e.target), 0);
});

inputElement.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
    // If there's no selection, enforce cursor position
    if (inputElement.selectionStart === inputElement.selectionEnd) {
        enforceCursorPosition(e.target);
    }
});

// Update formatting based on the current settings
function updateFormatting() {
    inputElement.value = formatNumber(inputElement.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
}

document.getElementById('decimalPlaces').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    decimalPlaces = parseInt(e.target.value);
    updateFormatting();
});

document.getElementById('unit').addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.key.match(/[0-9]/)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

document.getElementById('unit').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    unit = e.target.value;
    updateFormatting();
});

document.getElementById('unitPosition').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    unitPosition = e.target.value;
    updateFormatting();
});

document.getElementById('useDigitSeparator').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    useDigitSeparator = e.target.checked;
    updateFormatting();
});

document.getElementById('numberSystem').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    numberSystem = parseInt(e.target.value);
    updateFormatting();
});

const unitInputElement = document.getElementById('unit');

let activeInput = ""; // A flag to keep track of which input is currently active

inputElement.addEventListener('focus', () => {
    activeInput = "main";
});

unitInputElement.addEventListener('focus', () => {
    activeInput = "unit";
});

inputElement.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    if (activeInput !== "main") {
        return; // Exit early if the main input is not active
    }

    let targetValue = e ? e.target.value : inputElement.value;
    let rawValue = targetValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    
    // Ensure rawValue doesn't exceed 15 characters
    if (rawValue.length > 15) {
        rawValue = rawValue.substring(0, 15);
    }

    const formattedValue = formatNumber(rawValue);

    if (e) {
        e.target.value = formattedValue;
        enforceCursorPosition(e.target);
    } else {
        inputElement.value = formattedValue;
    }
});

function initializeConfigVariables() {
    decimalPlaces = parseInt(document.getElementById('decimalPlaces').value);
    unit = document.getElementById('unit').value;
    unitPosition = document.getElementById('unitPosition').value;
    useDigitSeparator = document.getElementById('useDigitSeparator').checked;
    numberSystem = parseInt(document.getElementById('numberSystem').value);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    initializeConfigVariables();
    inputElement.value = formatNumber('0');
});
```